# User click more button to clone and if user click add less button to remove but here it was validting the field and remove using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing the below issues:

If the user clicks "next" `button` before cloning, it should say you have 4  fields missing to validate. but if the user clicks the "addmore" button, and then clicks the next button, it should say you have 4 fields missing to validate. If the user fills any mandatory field in the **cloned div** and original div then clicks the next button, it should say you have 7 fields missing to validate. Getting confused I tried all the ways Nothing works

Here is the jquery code

```
function check_for_validation_removal(element){
    var parent_div = $(element).closest("div.cloned-row1,div.cloned-row2,div.cloned-row3,div.cloned-row4,div.cloned-row5").find("input[type='text'],#txt_schName option:selected");
  console.log(parent_div);
    console.log(parent_div.length);
    var invalid_ele = 0;
            parent_div.each(function () { 
               if($(this).val().trim().length == 0)
               {
                invalid_ele = invalid_ele + 1;
               }  
            });
    console.log(invalid_ele);
    if(parent_div.length == invalid_ele){
   parent_div.each(function () { 
   $(this).removeClass("required_field"); 
      $(this).rules('remove'); 
  });

        bind_validation();
        update_errors();
    }
```

Here is the complete fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/yg97yg19/6/)

Kindly suggest how I could resolve these issues.

Comment: why do you bind the `click` to `btn_less1` twice? You have this twice: `$(document).on('click', ".btn_less1", function () ` remove one with `bind_validation` function and I think it should work the way you want.

Comment: thanks @Zealander i did that still now working :(

Comment: @Zealander No actually what exactly i want is if the user click the next button initally it will say you have 4 field missing but once he click addmore button then if he click the next button still it should say you have  4 field missing but if the user enter any value in the mandatory field in the cloned one then he clicks the next it should say you have 9 fields missing :)

Comment: thanks @Zealandar You have solved the first issue :)

Comment: @Zealander sorry even the first issue was not solved because in the second panel add less button was not working :(

Comment: @any updates for the above question

Comment: Duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723669/clone-validation-using-jquery-partially-working

Comment: I would add an additional hidden input field that updates with the new cloned input id "_#" so that when you click add row you can only add a row if the last showing row is validated, otherwise you can show an error saying to fill out the first set before adding another.

Comment: Why you dont try `on('bind')`

Answer (score 5):

```
<div id="TextBoxesGroup" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">/*Html code here also*/</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 2;
    $("#addButton").click(function () {
        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<br><input type="text" name="ipt_Havg" id="ipt_Havg" class="ipt_Field required_field" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">');/*Same code paste here html*/
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
        counter++;
    });
    $("#removeButton").click(function () {
        if (counter == 1) {
            alert("No more File box to remove");
            return false;
        }
        counter--;
        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
    });
});


<div><input type='button' value='Add File' id='addButton'><input type='button' value='Remove File' id='removeButton'></div>
```