# Clone validation using jquery partially working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

1. Initially when the user click next button it will show the message
   as You have missed 7 fields. Please fill before submitted.
2. If the user clicked the add more button it will get clone without
   fill any of the mandatory field if user click next button. The
   message still shows You have missed 7 fields. Please fill before
   submitted
3. Once the user starts fills any of the field in the cloned one and he
   missed the rest of the mandatory fields from clone and original div then the   user click the next button it will show these many number of fields are missed.

```
function check_for_validation_removal(element) {
    var parent_div = $(element).closest("div.cloned-row1,div.cloned-row2,div.cloned-row3,div.cloned-row4,div.cloned-row5").find("input[type='text'],#txt_schName option:selected");
    console.log(parent_div);
    console.log(parent_div.length);
    var invalid_ele = 0;
    parent_div.each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
            invalid_ele = invalid_ele + 1;
        } 
    });
    console.log(invalid_ele);
    if (parent_div.length == invalid_ele) {
        parent_div.each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("required_field");
            $(this).rules('remove');
        });

        bind_validation();
        update_errors();
    }
}
```

I tried adding selector in on change still no luck.

```
$('.cloned_field').on('input','.cloned_div',function(e){
    if($(this).val().trim().length > 0)
    {

        $(this).addClass("required_field");
        var parent_div = $(this).closest("div.cloned-row1").find("input");
        parent_div.each(function () {
            $(this).addClass("required_field");
        });
    }
    check_for_validation_removal($(this));
    bind_validation(); 
});
```

Please help me where I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/yg97yg19/6/)

Comment: What's the issue? I've tried your fiddle and the correct number of fields are showing as required?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. In the fiddle if I don't enter anything and click "next" it says I'm missing 6 fields, which looks right. If I click "addmore" some new fields get added and clicking "next" updates the number to 9 (which still looks right).

Comment: Hi all initially when the user click next button it will work perfectly fine but once user click the clone button and again if user click the next button it should say you have 4 field to validate in the but the problem is here in the  second scenario if the user fills any one  of the mandatory field in the clone div and click the next it should validate the clone div and original div and it should say you have 7 field to validate this was not working

Comment: @Mahadevan - working fine for me. What exactly are you asking? Be concise and specific.

Comment: hi @aphextwix once the user click the addmore button then he click the next button it was validating the clone div but for me it should happen the user has to fill any one of the mandatory field in the clone div and click the next it should validate both clone div and original div and it should say you have 7 field to validate this was not working

Comment: @aphextwix did you notice the problem which i said

Comment: @ any luck for the above question or need some more input kindly please ask me

Comment: did you guys notice the issue kindly please message me

Comment: @Mahadevan the example in the fiddle works fine... Do you want the validation to happen after clicking `addmore` but before clicking `Next`?

Comment: initially when the user click next button it was validating the original div once the user click the addmore button  click the next button it was validating but for me it should happen the user has to fill any one of the mandatory field in the clone div and click the next it should validate both clone div and original div and it should say you have 7 field to validate this was not working

Comment: hi @Gildor can you please come for a chat i will explain even more if you not understand

Comment: try using the following format... $('body').on(eventName,object,function(e){});

Comment: @AkhileshSharma $('.cloned_field').on('input','.cloned_div',function(e){}); I have tried this

Comment: But i do agree with others... it doesnot seem to be with any errors... it is showing the right set of error messages.

Comment: @AkhileshSharma kindly please read my question error where working perfectly fine but I am facing other issue please see my question

Comment: so just to confirm you dont want the clone div to be validated right ?

Comment: I want the clone div should be validated when the user fill in any one of the mandatory field in the clone div until unless it should not validate the clone one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90560/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-akhilesh-sharma).

Comment: Is this a cross-post of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701667/user-click-more-button-to-clone-and-if-user-click-add-less-button-to-remove-but ?

Comment: With a combined bounty he can't even afford.

Comment: that isn't how bounties work. rep is removed when placing it, not when awarding it.

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware of that. Silly either way.

Comment: @akhilesh any luck for the above question

Comment: hi all any luck for the question

Comment: @Mahadevan, as others already said here. It seems to work in that fiddle. The message is updated after you hit **Add more** and **Next**. What browser are you using?

Comment: @mahadevan, what is your browser?

Comment: I am using chrome,firefox and ie11

Comment: @GustavoStraube it was not like that i want once the user click addmore button user to has to fill any of the mandatory field in the clone then only it has to validate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think the question is, the add-on fields should only be validated when a field within the add-on section has a value. so I have updated the `bind_validation()` and added a new function `addRemoveCloneValidation()` and removed allot which is not in relation to the question (though you still might need it).

```
    function bind_validation(){
        $(".required_field ").each(function(){
            $(this).rules("add", { 
                required:true,
            });
        });
        addRemoveCloneValidation();
    }

    function addRemoveCloneValidation(){
    $('div[id^="added"]').each(function(index, item){
       var needsValidation = false;
        $.each($(item).find('.required_field'), function(index, item){                      
            if($(item).val()) 
                needsValidation = true; 
            $(item).change(addRemoveCloneValidation);
        });
        $.each($(item).find('.required_field'), function(index, item){ 
            $(item).rules("add", { 
                required:needsValidation,
            });
            if(!needsValidation)
               $(item).removeClass('errRed'); 
        });
    });   
}
```

when a new row is added, `bind_validation` is called which then calls `addRemoveCloneValidation`. this then adds or removes the validation for all the clone inputs based on if any of inputs has a value.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yg97yg19/13/)

**EDIT**

Following your last comment

> 2) when the user click addmore button and user click next button for
>   the validation it should say You have missed 6 fields. Please fill
>   before submitted because the user has not fill any of the mandatory
>   field from the clone div

then you also need to remove 'Degree Date' from being mandatory, or don't set the 'Degree Date' when you clone.

```
$clone.find("input.deg_date")
  .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
  .removeData('datepicker')
  .unbind()
  .datepicker({
   dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
   changeMonth: true,
   yearRange: "-100:+0",
   changeYear: true,
   maxDate: new Date(),
   showButtonPanel: false,
});//.val(fulldate);       <--remove
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yg97yg19/14/)

**EDIT 2**

To manually call the validation on the form, you can use `$(".educationForm").valid();`.

I have added it to this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yg97yg19/18/) on line 141.

The less validation only works on the 'test' section. but can easily to used to be added to the school section.

Comment: thanks for the effort but still it was not match my question see There are three scenarios 1) initially when the user click next button the error message should say You have missed 6 fields. Please fill before submitted 2) when the user click addmore button and user click next button for the validation it should say You have missed 6 fields. Please fill before submitted because the user has not fill any of the mandatory field from the clone div 3) if the user start fill any of the mandatory from the clone then click next it should say you have You have missed 10 fields. this is wht i

Comment: That is how its working.. its just when you clone the education information it sets a value inside the date field which is required, therefore making that  section required. try deleting the date and the validation goes away for the section.

Comment: you are almost there could you please tell me in the Test Score field it has to accept only number how to do that

Comment: give the score input type="number"

Comment: when the user click add less button the validation was not detecting :(

Comment: added less button from line 130 of this http://jsfiddle.net/yg97yg19/16/ for the test section. you can take that and add it to the school section too.

Comment: hi sorry it was not there in the question but i need a help can you please hlep when the user click add less button the validation has to reduce the count please :)

Comment: Hi add less button functionality was working that's great but in the top the error message counting was not reduced

Comment: Thank you so much I gave bounty to you